# CanActivateでUrlTreeを返しても正常にビューが遷移されない。

Tags: angular

こちらのチュートリアルを見ながらRailsとAngularの基本的なユーザー認証の方法を学習していたのですが`CanActivate`の動作でわからない点が出てきました。
https://hackernoon.com/angular-2-and-ruby-on-rails-user-authentication-part-4-49d550c5869a

このチュートリアルでは以下のように`CanActivate`を使い、権限のないユーザーが`/profile`にアクセスした時に`/`にビュー遷移するのですが、

```
  canActivate() {
    if (this.tokenService.userSignedIn()) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

ドキュメントによると`canActivate`が`UrlTree`を返せば、現在のビュー遷移がキャンセルされ、返された`UrlTree`を元に新しくビュー遷移が行われるはずなので以下のように書き換えてみました。
https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

```
  canActivate() {
    if (this.tokenService.userSignedIn()) {
      return true;
    }
    return this.router.createUrlTree(['/']);
  }
```

ですが、`Profile`コンポーネントは表示されなかったものの、ルートビューなら表示されるはずのWellcomeテキストも表示されずナビゲーションバーだけの表示になってしまいました。

なぜルートビューの`UrlTree`を渡してもビュー遷移しなかったのでしょうか？
Angularのバージョンは`7.2.5`を使っています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

確かに @angular/router のバージョン7.2.5であれば CanActivateで UrlTreeを返せば遷移するはずです。`ng version` コマンドでインストールされているRouterのバージョンを確認してみてもらいたいです。

また、Routerのデバッグであれば、 `RouterModule.forRoot()` の第二引数で渡せるオプションに、 `enableTracing` というものがあります。どのようにRouterやGuardが動作するかのログがconsoleに流れますので、そちらも参考にしてみると解決が早まるかもしれません。

Comment: すいません、再度確認してみると現象が再現しなくなり正常動作するようになっていました。Routerなど各モジュールごとにバージョンが異なる可能性があること、Routerのデバック方法など勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。